# Linq Using Contains On An Array

Tags: arrays, linq, datatable

Im trying to query a datatable using linq, ideally what I would like to do is compare a column of strings to an array of strings, returning those that match.

Any ideas?

Cheers in advance

CM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use one of the `Field<T>` methods of [DataRowExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx).

```
var foo = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
          where bar.Contains(r.Field<string>("barColumn"))
          select r;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myDB.Where(x=> array.Contains(x));
```

Comment: Is that Linq To SQL?  I cant seem to convert the syntax to work with mt datatable.

Comment: Some ORM Providers may cause this query to eager load meaning the entire table is loaded into memory before filtering on Contains.

Comment: @Daz Lewis, this is linq2sql, I wrote it in the format of EF, also I didn't see there is problem with this for other ORMs, for example linq2nhibernate works like EF in this case.